# Attempting to get the last node in a Binary Tree

Tags: python-3.x, binary-tree

The tree is backed by a BinaryNode which store pointers to a parent, left child, and right child. I believe that I am close, but I can not get the last node.
The tester tree I am using is:

```
      0
     / \
    /   \
   1     2
  / \   / 
 3   4 5 

# ---------- Find the last element ----------

def _find_last(self, node):           # PARAMETER node: the root of the tree
    # Start by going right

    if self._has_right(node):         # _has_right takes a node and returns True if there is a node

        node = node.get_right()       # get_right takes a node that will then return the right child

        self._find_last(node)

    # Go left if there is not a right

    elif self._has_left(node):         # _has_left takes a node and returns True if there is a node

        node = node.get_left()         # get_left takes a node that will then return the left child

        self._find_last(node)       

    return node                        # return the last node in the tree
```

I should get the node that has 5, but I end up getting the one with 2. During testing, the function does reach the node with 5, but still returns the node with 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you should be setting `node` to the return value of the `self.find_last` calls. Right now, you are returning the value of the parent of the last node in the tree, since you don't return the value of the `self.find_last` call.

You can restructure your code to make it cleaner:

```py
def _find_last(self, node):     
    if self._has_right(node):        
        return self._find_last(node.get_right())
    elif self._has_left(node):        
        return self._find_last(node.get_left())       
    return node
```

Comment: Thanks this is really helpful! You initially said that I needed to set the return value self._find_last, but in your code snippet, you just return the self._find_last calls. I did this instead node = self._find_last(node.get_right()).

Comment: Hello, sorry about the confusion. I offered two possible solutions to your problem and the second one I thought would be clearer to read since you do not change the value of the parameter.